# RasPi 4B Bridge wlan1 to eth0 in Layer 2

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

I'm looking to bridge [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BJS8FXD) USB-WiFi card that supports AP/STA Mode with the Pi 4B's Ethernet Interface over Layer 2. Connection will go [Router]<-->[Pi's WiFi]<-->[Pi's Ethernet]<-->[Client Device/Laptop]. Does anyone know of a simple script to accomplish this? I've tried creating a bridge interface br0 but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this on Bookworm? NetworkManager should make it easy to configure this

Comment: I know right, it seems so simple but has given me so many issues...what exactly is bookworm?

Comment: Oh, sorry, Bookworm is the codename for latest stable Debian release. Debian is the Linux distro that Raspberry Pi OS uses.